# Getting a dynamically created folder name using mkdir() in PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

I am dynamically creating folders for each user in my php file with

```
mkdir("Userfiles/".$company."_".$time_stamp);
```

I want to save that directory in a variable or any other and I have to use the directory name for saving my .txt files in it

```
$myFile = "exfiles/".str_replace(" ","-",$_POST['company'])."_CC Booth furnishings ".$order_type."_".$time_stamp.".txt";
```

In the place of 'exfiles' I need to give the dynamically created directory name.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: 1) You can just save the string you pass into mkdir. 2) You should really be sanitizing user input data before creating a folder using it.

Comment: @Dogbert Or, really, before doing _anything_ with it besides holding it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks for advices, I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$dirname = "Userfiles/".$company."_".$time_stamp;
mkdir($dirname);
$myFile = $dirname . str_replace(" ","-",$_POST['company'])."_CC Booth furnishings ".$order_type."_".$time_stamp.".txt";
```

As stated in the comments of your question:

**Don't use $_POST data directly to manipulate files on the server. Always sanitize it**

Comment: Thank u, quick ans worked like a gem. Thans again for saving my time