# generate directory on register in php

Tags: php, mkdir

I was wondering how I could create a new directory for each user that registered to my site so that they would be able to upload their material to their own directory. I've looked all over the place but haven't really found anything that I could use, because I need it to be dynamic, and I've only found how to name the directory by specifying the name in mkdir.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **A:** You haven't looked long enough and/or haven't used the right keyword(s). ;-)

Comment: sounds like a bad idea, they dont need a directory each

Comment: Here, 30 seconds on Google ("dynamic folder creation php mkdir") yielded http://stackoverflow.com/a/15252572/ - Having shown us what you tried, would've been a bonus. ;-) Try spending 3 **days** on Google (as I do at times) instead of seconds/minutes please.  Perseverance has its rewards.

Answer (score 1):

Say `$user` contains username of the user this will do the work.

```
$user = "youruser";

if (!file_exists("path/to/".$user)) {
    mkdir("path/to/".$user, 0755, true);
}
```

be careful about permissions and input sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mkdir` function : `mkdir("some/path/{$username}", 0755);`

Comment: *"and I've only found how to name the directory by specifying the name in mkdir."*

Comment: @Fred-ii- However, this would fulfill the "dynamic" portion of the question (which appears to be the main thing being asked about). As a note to Andre, however, make sure that your user names are sanitized!

Comment: @ChrisForrence OP's `effort=NULL;`